# MongoDb aggregation over 2 diff collections in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

I have two collections
1. `usersCollection`
2. `interactionCollection`

Now I get an array of users and their contacts emails list from `usersCollection`

(V) is Visible interactions to super user
(H) is Hidden interactions to super user

```
allUsersArr = [user1EmailArr1, user1EmailArr3, user1EmailArr3]

allEmailsArr = [jim@zxc.com,tom@zxc.com,mark@zxc.com,glen@zxc.com,maria@zxc.com]
```

I take these users and get their interactions with those contacts based on their visibility to the super user.

Now some of the contacts are common across the users

For ex. in my case

`jim@zxc.com,mark@zxc.com,maria@zxc.com`

are common but their visibility to the super user are different.

Next I get all the interactions for these users' `emails` using an aggregation on `interactionCollection`.

```
interactionCollection.aggregate([
     { $match: {userId: {$in:allUsersArr}} },
     { $unwind: "$interactions" },
     { $match:  {"interactions.emailId": {$in: allEmailsArr}} },
     { $project:{ "interactions":"$interactions" } },
     { $group:{ _id:"$interactions.interactionType", count:{$sum:1} }
}]).exec(function (err, callback){//Results........})
```

Now because I'm querying for interactions in one go, the interactions don't respect the visibility of the contacts emails set by each users as the contacts emails are common and even though **user1EmailArr2** and **user1EmailArr3** have jim@zxc.com hidden to super user, but this contacts email is visibile set by user1EmailArr1.

I get the interactions for user1EmailArr2 and user1EmailArr3 with jim@zxc.com anyway.

In reality the number of interactions for each user based on visibility seetings are :

1. Interactions of user1EmailArr1 = 24
2. Interactions of user1EmailArr2 = 30
3. Interactions of user1EmailArr3 = 6
4. Total = 60.

> But the total number of interactions that I get is 80

Now, how do I map each user's contacts emails such that the visibility set is respected.

Things I tried

1. 1.I tried using async.each to fetch all each interaction separately but it doesn't wait until it gets each user's interaction coz I have callback inside the aggregation.
2. Denormalizing the interactions collections is out of question for
   now.